# Loci of intersection points of two curves

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

There are two continuous, negatively-sloped curves,**A** and **B**. They intersect at least once ,say at $(x,y)$. If I introduce a third curve **C**, whose X axis intercept has a higher magnitude than that of **B**, then the intersection point(s), with **A** will lie further to the right. If the Y axis intercept of **C** has a higher magnitude than that of **B**, then the intersection point(s) will lie further up (wrt.  $(x,y)$ ). Can you prove this, for any functional form of the curves ? This result is geometrically obvious. The proof is simple for $3$ intersecting straight lines.

Answer (score 1):

Without any further restrictions on the curves there does not have to be any relationship. One can draw two negatively sloped curves that intersect any number of times.

Comment: you are absolutely correct. i have modified the question.thanks!

Comment: I think it still does not make sense after your edit. The curves $C$ and $A$ can intersect any number of times as can the curves $B$ and $A$, so it does not make sense to say that the intersection points of $C$ with $A$ will lie further to the right than those of $B$ with $A$. Maybe you want to assume that $A$ and $B$ intersect only once and $A$ and $C$ intersect only once?

Comment: let me think about that for a bit...meanwhile if you have a proof for this (if the curves intersect only once), could you please share it ? thanks!